# Question about dense trajectory on $k$-dimensional torus under rotation map

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Today when I was doing ergodic theory problems I faced with following problem:

Assume rotation map on  $k$-dimensional torus  under $\alpha=(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$
then orbit of all $x$ in $k$-dimensional torus is
 dense if and only if vector $\alpha$ is irrationally independent

( means $n_o+n_1\alpha_1+...+n_n\alpha_n=0 \quad  \text{then}\quad  n_i=0 \quad \text{for all}\quad n_i \in \mathbb Z$ )

I solved density of orbit of irrational rotation on circle but when i generalized it to torus problem couldn't be solved by that technique. on the other side I tried to translate  trajectory  on $2$ dim torus to unit square which trajectory starts from zero but how to find angle of trajectory   associated to rotation.

"Some Questions has been asked but their answers wasn't clear for me?
I will be appreciate if add some hint.

Comment: "how to find angle of trajectory associated to rotation.": if the map takes ($x,y$) to $(x+\alpha_1,y+\alpha_2$), the angle is simply $tan^{-1}(\alpha_2/\alpha_1)$....